# Excel VBA multiple runtime errors in a macro to send data between two sheets

Tags: excel, vba

I have a code made to send data from user static form field (CAB) type (Sheet AJOUTER_PV) to a Sheet "Inventaire".

The work around area is set to a range of two lines called "table1". Example I type in a manual static form field an ID CALLED "CAB" and that unique id, is going to be sent to the first, second, third... lines's first rows "CAB" each time I hit the macro button (and using vlookup on other rows data displays on each line).

Problem is that I am getting errors 13 type mismatch, declaration errors, compilation errors, not defined block (from `LastRow`.......to `.row` block)... so I cannot even resolve one to get new one.

I expect error related to `WX` `za` `WsPV` `WsInv`..syntax and related declaration settings.

Full code:

```vb
Option Explicit
    
Sub Macro1()
    '
    ' Macro1 Macro
    '
    Dim WsPV As Range
    Dim WsInv As Range
    Set WsPV = Worksheets("AJOUTER_PV")
    Set WsInv = Worksheets("Inventaire")
    Dim Id  As Variant
    Set Id = WsPV.Cells(6, "K").Value
    Dim LastRow As Long
    Dim WX As Range
    Set WX = Range("table1").ListObjects
    Dim za As Range
    Set za = WsInv.WX
    Dim LastRow As Variant
    
    LastRow = WsInv.Find(What:=" * ", _
    After:=WsInv.Cells(1), _
    Lookat:=xlPart, _
    LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
    SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
    SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
    MatchCase:=False).Row
    
    WsInv.Parent.Cells(LastRow + 1, 1).Value = Id.Value
    '
End Sub
```

Any help will be appreciated. Regards.

Comment: There is only one compile-time error in this code, the duplicate declaration of `LastRow`. Remove one of them. There are numerous runtime errors though due to all variables declared `As Range` even though none of them stores ranges.

Comment: So what you suggest with the declared variables.. to remove declarations for example?

Comment: To declare them as what they are supposed to contain. `WsPV` is supposed to contain a worksheet, so declare it `As Worksheet`.